# Struct or Enum to use for serialization keys?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any reason why Apple prefers using structs over enums in the Lister demo for declaring keys for serialization? Is there might be some benefits?

For example:

```
private struct SerializationKeys {
    static let text = "text"
    static let uuid = "uuid"
    static let completed = "completed"
    ...
    //duplicated key!
    static let descriptionText = "text"
}
```

Here we might have potential duplicates for keys. It's not a big question for small objects (don't forget copy/paste :)), but for large objects with tens fields it can be a real problem.

With enum we don't have such a problem:

```
    private enum SerializationKeys : String {
    case text = "text"
    case uuid = "uuid"
    case completed = "completed"
    //...
    case descriptionText = "text"
    //here we have compiler's warning: Raw value for enum case is not unique
}
```

Will be happy to hear some thoughts on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do the same thing, sometimes, and here's why.

With a struct, my values are directly available: so, if SerializationKeys is a struct, then `SerializationKeys.text` is a string.

But with an enum, the enum is the value. If SerializationKeys is an enum, then `SerializationKeys.text` is *not* a string; it's an enum. If I want the string, I have to fetch it explicitly, as the enum's `rawValue`. Sometimes, that's just too nutty. On the other hand, if it's acceptable, or if there's another reason why this makes a good enum, then fine, I'll use an enum.

To put it another way: if this is just a glorified namespace for some constants, a struct with static members seems simplest. An enum is for a *switch*, i.e. something that needs to exist in exactly one of several possible states.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's reason for choosing a `struct` here seems to be purely semantic. `SerializationKeys.descriptionText` is a property. `SerializationKey.DescriptionText` is a type. And it is kind of semantically weird to use a *type* as a *key*.

True, in this particular instance the `SerializationKey.DescriptionText` type happens to have a "raw" value associated with it. But as I understand it, raw values are really only intended to be used as a sort of "bridging layer" layer between C enums. Using it for keys like this is kind of a hack.

Comment: SerializationKey enum is-a type, and .descriptionText is an instance having the type?  You define all the instances when and only when you declare the enum.  Its not so weird to use enum members as keys.